# Project runs on Heroku locally, but not online

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was deploying my project to Heroku and tried locally with the te comand `heroku local web`. That works perfectly, but, when I sended the the project to run online, I got this error on Heroku logs:

```
2018-02-20T17:23:21.824637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

2018-02-20T17:23:33.111420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sagaedu.herokuapp.com request_id=b04299fc-6ea8-41d3-a994-9a064b6d98af fwd="177.39.172.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-02-20T17:24:03.282786+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sagaedu.herokuapp.com request_id=88a02575-95dc-4450-b9b4-e53f65770454 fwd="177.39.172.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-02-20T17:27:04.669222+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sagaedu.herokuapp.com request_id=c56fa212-d104-4569-b916-439e3d003398 fwd="177.39.172.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-02-20T17:32:00.954709+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=sagaedu.herokuapp.com request_id=c8126dd0-0868-4d12-9421-2d2d7b94e73c fwd="177.39.172.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

2018-02-20T17:35:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user

2018-02-20T17:36:00.992071+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to down

2018-02-20T17:36:00.794498+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 07a1f9df by user

2018-02-20T17:36:00.794498+00:00 app[api]: Release v15 created by user

2018-02-20T17:35:16.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

2018-02-20T17:38:16.055964+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=sagaedu.herokuapp.com request_id=12e85de9-ac80-413c-b022-8f8fb91944aa fwd="177.39.172.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn saga.saga.wsgi --log-file -
```

Comment: what is name of your project? If it's "saga" then in your Procfile it should be `web: gunicorn saga.wsgi --log-file -`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It was because I ran the `git init` in a wrong directory. And that was why "saga.saga" was there.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you scaled your dynos to zero,
try the following command to set dynos to one

```
 heroku ps:scale web=1
```

you can find more info here
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes

Comment: I already tried this, but I get another error: `Scaling dynos... !
 ▸    Couldn't find that process type.`

Comment: I'm almost sure that the problem is on the Procfile, but I don't know why, where or what.

Comment: I'll upload my configurations.

Comment: it seems fine, although why do you have saga.saga twice, or its the name of the app ?

Comment: I found the error. That was because I run the `git init` in a wrong directory. And that was why "saga.saga" was there.